# Html Doesnt read my js functions

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, slideshow

Im using react to create a slideshow, the problem is that my html doesnt find the function to change the slide.
It goes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *>
  </header>
  <main id="peli">
    <div id="root">
    </div>
    <script src="dist/app.bundle.js">plusSlides(2)</script>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

In my js file I have a ReactDOM.render to render my html and a function to change the slides, plusSlides, but for some reason the program cant find the function plusSlides. I use webpack to compile my file.

Comment: the only reactjs lookin' thing you got there is maybe the `#root`

Comment: yes, I dont think the problem is with react part of the code, because the code works, but  the function to change the slide its not found

Comment: After webpack compiles your file, the `plusSildes` function is not available the way it would if you define `plusSlides` function normally in normal JavaScript. Why not include image slider inside React itself. That is the normal way to do things in React--do most of the things (mainly those that require JS) inside the React App itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack normally doesn't expose things to window. You are expected to initialise from javascript.
But you can tell webpack to [export a library](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#expose-the-library) which will work like you want.

All you have to do is add this to the output config.

```
output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    library: 'webpackLib',
    libraryTarget: 'window',
},
```

You have different options for the target, look in to documentation for more info.