# Symfony 4 Javascript function not defined

Tags: symfony, webpack, symfony4, webpack-encore

I have created a app.js (and app.scss) to use with Symfony Encore.

```
└───assets
    ├───css
    │   └───app.scss
    └───js
        └───app.js
```

app.js:

```
/**
 * Name: app.js
 * Desc: Main application javascript
 */

var $ = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-sass');
require('../css/app.scss');

// Initialize tooltips
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
});

var openLoginModal = function(element){
    $('#login-modal').modal('show');
}
```

In one of my templates, I want to be able to set the 'onclick' event to call the 'openLoginModal' function defined in app.js

```
<a class="btn btn-info navbar-btn navbar-right" data-toggle="login-modal" onclick="openLoginModal(this)">Login</a>
```

When the anchor element is clicked the following error is displayed in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: openLoginModal is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):29)
```

I assume that I cannot access the functions from app.js for some reason, but I don't know enough about webpack to understand why this is

Comment: Try to change `var openLoginModal` to `Window.prototype.openLoginModal`.
I believe you are trying to access a global function, but your script is inside a webpack module.

Comment: I just answered this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49316775/9083959

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
(function ($, window)
{
   window.openLoginModal = function(element){
       $('#login-modal').modal('show');
   }
}(jQuery, window);
```